# Will index on joined table be used here?

Tags: oracle, index

`select * from employee, department where employee.id = department.id`

department.id is primary key on department

My question is will index created on  department.id(internally created index on primary key by oracle) be used while `employee.id = department.id` i.e. while finding corresponding row_id in department table

Answer (score 0):

HASH JOIN - no

NESTED LOOPS JOIN - yes, depends on statistics

Oracle can not use index range scan for join predicates when performing a hash join. But it can use indexes for other predicates for the `probe table` ("second" table), so hash join does not automatically result in a full table scan of the probe table.

Comment: why B tree index(created on `department.id `) can not be used while `employee.id = department.id` to find corresponding row from department table ?

Comment: @user3198603 Because a hash join searches for hash values, not actual values. Indexes contain actual values, not hash values.